# Check IsInRole without requiring the Authorize attribute?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, isinrole

I have created my own Authorize attribute called Authorise...

```
Imports System.Security.Principal

<AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method Or AttributeTargets.[Class], Inherited:=True, AllowMultiple:=True)>
Public Class AuthoriseAttribute
    Inherits AuthorizeAttribute

    Public Overrides Sub OnAuthorization(filterContext As AuthorizationContext)

        Dim CookieName As String = FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName

        If Not filterContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated OrElse filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Cookies Is Nothing OrElse filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Cookies(CookieName) Is Nothing Then
            HandleUnauthorizedRequest(filterContext)
            Return
        End If

        Dim AuthCookie = filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Cookies(CookieName)
        Dim AuthTicket = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(AuthCookie.Value)
        Dim Roles As String() = AuthTicket.UserData.Split(","c)

        Dim UserIdentity = New GenericIdentity(AuthTicket.Name)
        Dim UserPrincipal = New GenericPrincipal(UserIdentity, Roles)

        filterContext.HttpContext.User = UserPrincipal
        MyBase.OnAuthorization(filterContext)

   End Sub

End Class
```

I've done this so I can use the roles parameter on the attribute, like this...

```
<Authorise(Roles:="Admin")>
```

This works perfectly on my pages that require authorisation.  However, on my main page, which does not require authorisation (and therefore does not have the Authorise attribute) I would like to display different items depending on whether the user is (a) logged in and (b) whether they are an admin or not.  For example...

```
@If HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated Then
    ' Display a welcome message (this works)
    @If HttpContext.Current.User.IsInRole("Admin") Then
        ' Display a settings link (this does not work)
    End If
End If
```

The "welcome message" part fires but the "settings link" part does not.  This makes sense because this view does not have the Authorise attribute.

How can I check the IsInRole on pages that don't have the Authorise attribute?

Comment: did u get a solution for this?

Comment: Sorry for the delay.  I did not get a solution to this no.  As a temporary workaround I am dealing with Authentication in Application_AuthenticateRequest.  I am still hoping for a solution that allows me to use the Action Filter though as people have mentioned it is the better way on other posts.

Comment: Thank you for that. I tried 'Application_OnPostAuthenticateRequest' but when I debug the code, it gets called too many times. Which is kind of an overkill. I just needed IsInRole in few partial views. So I have managed to create a 'ManualOnAuthorization' method which only gets called whenever needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have a proper solution for this. Just a work around that may help before someone posts the proper solution.

I use, [Authorize] attribute for the actions but whenever I am in a partial view, I do a manual 'OnAuthorization'.

```
public class Authorize : AuthorizeAttribute
{
 public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
 {
   ....
 }

 public static void ManualOnAuthorization(HttpContext context)
 {
    if (context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated && context.User.Identity.AuthenticationType == "Forms")
    {
        FormsIdentity fIdent = (FormsIdentity)context.User.Identity;
        var user = new CustomUser(fIdent.Ticket.UserData);
        var ci = new CustomIdentity(user);
        var p = new CustomPrincipal(ci);
        HttpContext.Current.User = p;
        Thread.CurrentPrincipal = p;
    }
 }
}
```

I have put it in Authorize class and use it as following in a partial view.

```
@if(User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        Authorize.ManualOnAuthorization(HttpContext.Current); 
        if (User.IsInRole("Admin"))
        {
        }
    }
```

Comment: For me, I want to display my "Admin" link on every page (if logged in as an Admin) and therefore I have it in my Layout page.  So I think your temporary solution would be called just as often as my temporary solution.  Thanks though.

Comment: Just as a thought. Let's say we have 100k views in a day and only 20k views are for logged in users. In that case ManualOnAuthorization will be called only 20k times. Cause we have condition User.Identity.IsAuthenticated. Where as 'Application_OnPostAuthenticateRequest' gets called 3 to 4 times for each view, no matter they are logged in or not. thnx

Comment: Good point actually.  I'd guess most of the time users will not be logged in on our website so this is a good workaround for now.